# Remove part of string between 2 brackets containing a specific word

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to make a function called RemoveError, that checks if a string contains the word "Error" inside 2 brackets with other text. If so, I need to remove the 2 brackets sorrounding "Error" and everything inside it.

Example:

```
var Result = RemoveError("Lorem Ipsum (Status: Hello) (Error: 14) (Comment: Some text)");
```

Result will return:
"Lorem Ipsum (Status: Hello) (Comment: Some text)"

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this Regex pattern:

```
public string RemoveError(string input) {
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"\(Error\:\s[0-9]{1,3}\)\s", "");
}
```

I am assuming that your error code is numeric and between 1 and 3 digits long. If that is not the case, you need to adapt that part of the expression. I am additionally removing one extra whitespace after the error part, because otherwise you would end up with 2 whitespaces in between.

```
\( - opening paranthesis
Error - match the word Error
\: - match the colon
\s - match a whitespace
[0-9]{1,3} - match 1 to 3 characters in the range from 0-9
\) - match a closing paranthesis
\s - match a whitespace
```

Output:

> Lorem Ipsum (Status: Hello) (Comment: Some text)

Comment: Wow, thank you some much! This worked perfect, just what I needed :)